# jquery iframe load entered when the iframe length is 0

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have a page with iframe on it (called frame1). When the iframe is loaded the page needs to call a javascript function on the iframe passing it a parameter.

```
$("iframe#frame1").load(function () {
        if(frame1.length == 0)
        {
            alert("Error");
        }
        else
        {
            frame1.showStatus(<%= hidStatus.Value.ToLower() %>);
        }
    });
```

Sometimes though rather than showing the status it displayed the alert "Error". What do you think happen guys? What can I do to make sure the "load" function entered when iframe is loaded completely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking if an iframe exists after the iframe is loaded.

can do the following to check if the iframe is loaded completely and then show your status...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if($("#frame1").length == 0) {
        alert("Error");
    } else {
        $("#frame1").load(function() {
            // showStatus
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Actually, $("#frame1").load(function() is enough. No need to check length, since I know the object is there... but doesn't heart anyway. Thanks.